# Show flask security roles in jinja2

Tags: python, flask-security, flask-mongoengine

I've created roles and assigned the to users.
I can show the current logged in users name with {{current_user}} in jinja2.
How do I show a users role(s) in jinja2?

For example:
Hi {{current_user}}, you have the roles: {{roles}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass those values as kargs in the render_template.

```
from flask import render_template
from flask_login import current_user

@app.route("/roles")    
def my_route():
    return render_template("roles.html", current_user=current_user, roles=current_user.roles)
```

Comment: Thank you.
Now it shows as: Your role is: [<Role: developer>] . How can I have it show only "developer"?

Comment: I figured it out by in template put {{current_user.roles[0]}}
Thank you.

Comment: Ahh no, because a new problem has occurred. With {{current_user.roles[0]}} it ofc only show the first role if a person has multiple roles. How to show all roles names not being a tuple.

Comment: print type(current_user.roles[0]) and let me know what type it has